# Drawing a points with CAShapeLayer not always in defined scale

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, cashapelayer, cgpoint

I draw points and i expect to receive a line with a constant width but sometimes the width of the point expands like a trapeze geometry.
This is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

CAShapeLayer *_leftStrokeLayer;
CGMutablePathRef _leftstrokePath;

- (void)SetUpStrokeLayer
{

  _leftStrokeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  _leftStrokeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
  _leftStrokeLayer.lineWidth = 6.0f;
  _leftStrokeLayer.lineCap = @"round";
  _leftStrokeLayer.frame = self.bounds;
  _leftStrokeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  _leftStrokeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

  [self.layer insertSublayer:_leftStrokeLayer above:_imageView.layer];
}


- (void)drawPoint:(CGPoint)leftPoint
{
 if (_leftstrokePath == nil)
    {
            _leftStrokeLayer.path = nil;

            _leftstrokePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGPathMoveToPoint(_leftstrokePath, nil, leftPoint.x, leftPoint.y);
    }

     CGPathAddLineToPoint(_leftstrokePath, nil, leftPoint.x, leftPoint.y);
     CGPathMoveToPoint(_leftstrokePath, nil, leftPoint.x, leftPoint.y);
     _leftStrokeLayer.path = _leftstrokePath;
}


- (void)clearLeftStrokePath
{
  if (_leftstrokePath)
  {
      CGPathRelease(_leftstrokePath);
  }
  _leftstrokePath = nil;
  _leftStrokeLayer.path = nil;
}
```

This is what i want :

[image: good line]
[image: another good line]

Sometimes i get this:

[image: bad line]
[image: another bad line]